# Show specific row data in handlebars without using each clause

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

When I want to display multiple rows of data using handlebars, I use `{{#each row}} {{/each}}`, but I also want to display just one piece of data in a specified row of `result`.

I tried doing `{{result.some_field}}` as well as `{{result[0].some_field}}`. The former didn't display anything but the latter gave me an `parse error` pointing to the array index: `Expecting 'ID', 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'BOOLEAN', 'DATA', got 'INVALID'`

Comment: Did you try `{{result.0.some_field}}`?

Comment: Yes. It works! Where can I read about this? Also, you might want to post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Handlebars, dot notation is used for both object properties and array elements; there is no bracket notation. So the correct syntax is:

```
{{result.0.some_field}}
```

For more info, see this tutorial:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-handlebars--net-27761

The official docs are rather spotty, so I recommend following a couple different tutorials to learn Handlebars completely.